# Why can't get IgnoreGravity within RelativeLayout to work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I have two buttons. I want one to be aligned at the top center of the application. I want to get the other button to ignore the gravity settings and go where I tell it. How do I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/the_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centered Button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/relative_layout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/the_button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Button"
        android:ignoreGravity="@id/relative_layout" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use gravity attribute of RelativeLayout, elements within RelativeLayout can be positioned with additional attributes. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/the_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Centered Button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/the_button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Random Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

See [RelativeLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) and [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for more information about usage of RelativeLayout.